# How create PageParamters from URL in wicket?

Tags: java, url, wicket

Wicket internally creates from url and passed [PageParameters](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/request/mapper/parameter/PageParameters.html) to it's components. Is is need from some test to create these parameters from url.

Does wicket provide public api for PageParameters creation?

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParametersEncoder` for that purpose.